# Is there a better way to get `std::tuple::operator==` to leverage `operator==` from another namespace?

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I'm using a C `struct` (that I do not control) and wrote a freestanding `operator==` implementation for it in a namespace.  I have another class that has that C `struct` as a member and that also has an `operator==` implementation.  Originally I had:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct Foo
{
    int x;
};

struct Bar
{
    Foo foo;
    int y;
};

namespace foo_ops
{
    bool operator==(const Foo& f1, const Foo& f2)
    {
        return f1.x == f2.x;
    }
}

bool operator==(const Bar& b1, const Bar& b2)
{
    using namespace foo_ops;
    return b1.foo == b2.foo && b1.y == b2.y;
}
```

which works.  I'd like to change the `operator==(const Bar&, const Bar&)` to use `std::tuple` instead:

```cpp
bool operator==(const Bar& b1, const Bar& b2)
{
    using namespace foo_ops;
 
    auto asTuple = [](const Bar& b)
    {
        return std::tie(b.foo, b.y);
    };

    return asTuple(b1) == asTuple(b2);
}
```

but that fails to resolve because the compiler won't choose `foo_ops::operator==` when comparing the `Foo` members.  Argument-dependent lookup doesn't help here since the `Foo` `struct` is declared in a different namespace from the corresponding `operator==`.

It apparently does work if I add a `using foo_ops::operator==;` declaration in the global scope.  That declaration does not help if used in the function's scope.  A globally-scoped `using namespace foo_ops;` directive also does not help.

My questions:

- Is there any way to get `std::tuple::operator==` to choose `foo_ops::operator==` without a globally-scoped `using` declaration? (Or perhaps I should give up on having `operator==(const Foo&, const Foo&)` live in a separate namespace and move it to the global one?) I suspect that the answer is no, and `using foo_ops::operator==;` isn't too bad, but maybe I'm missing some alternative.
- Not that I'd really want to use a globally-scoped `using namespace foo_ops;` directive, but why does that fail when `using foo_ops::operator==;` succeeds?

Comment: Why not just put `Foo` in a namespace, as good custom would be.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica `Foo` comes from a C library that I do not control.

Comment: So wrap the library properly, not just adding ops: `namespace FooCPP { struct Foo : ::Foo {}; }` - `FooCpp::Foo` will convert in any library call that takes a `::Foo*`.

Comment: it works because `Foo` is also in global namespace, so ADL would pickup it.

Comment: considered putting foo_ops::operator== in the same namespace as Foo?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I mentioned that: "Or perhaps I should give up on having `operator==(const Foo&, const Foo&)` live in a separate namespace..."

Comment: Operators *really should* be in the same namespace as the types they operate on

Comment: @Caleth Yes, but I don't control the type being operated on, and I'd rather not pollute the global namespace.  StoryTeller's suggestion of making a wrapper class in the operator's namespace might be acceptable though.